# Class Duplicate on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.0)

**Build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.4.3'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

**Build.gradle:app**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.denuncieagora'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.denuncieagora"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"

    // Dagger - Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.46.1'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.2"
}
```